# Whats exactly does tst.b or tst.w instruction do?

Tags: assembly, embedded, msp430

I understand its supposed to "Test destination", but what exactly does that mean?
The operations for .w and .b are below:
dst+0FFFFh+1 dst+0FFh+1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally `test` means: combine the two values using bitwise AND, then set the status register according to the result, but do not store the result itself.

On the MSP430, the `TST` instruction has only one argument; in this case, "testing a value" seems to be identical to "comparing a value to 0".

And, indeed, [the manual](http://mspgcc.sourceforge.net/manual/x223.html) of some unknown compiler for the MSP430 says:

> `TST(.B) xxx` is an abbreviation of `CMP(.B) #0, xxx`

Comment: How could this instruction affect the status register?

Comment: he said set status register according to the result. I'm asking what part of the status register gets set.

Comment: Since he said normally the set status register according to the result. I'm asking what part of the status register gets set "normally". Since this case is not normal, does it still affect the status register and if so, how?                                                                                                                                  --No need to be a dick @fuz

Comment: @Destreation Martin Rosenau explained exactly what `TST` means on MSP430: It's an abbreviation for `CMP` with one operand being `#0`. Martin even linked that manual for you. In there, you can surely find what flags `CMP` sets and from that you can conclude trivially what flags `TST` sets, as `TST` is just a shorthand for `CMP`.

Comment: @Destreation Specifically, [this page](http://mspgcc.sourceforge.net/manual/x82.html) explains what flags the MSP430 has and how instructions affect them.